# Validation in imagebutton, button not occuring

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, validation is not occurring at button_click and imagebutton_click. Why could it be so?

I also gave same validation group to all validators and button and also CAUSEVALIDATION "true" in button

Please help solve this.

Comment: This question looks very unclear to me :).

Comment: you forgot to paste your codes

Comment: She wants to know the reason, even she has placed causes validation = true and assigned validation group , why validation is not occuring on button click event.

Comment: @AmRan: How about tidying up the question for her - more likely to get some answers then. You should be able to edit it.

Comment: @Nick - i am not able to edit. I have only two options link and flag..

Comment: i want occure validation on button click event @ younes

Comment: and what type of code u talking about? @ Jhourlad Estrella

Comment: i cant understand your answer @ AmRan

Comment: can you paste some of your code here. I think you are using ASP.Net with either VB or C#

Comment: ya AmRan you r very good understand my problem in this question

Answer (score 0):

Add validation group to image button too and check. Also check if your image button has image in it. Other wise it will not fire events

**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" CssClass="text_box_password" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_password" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="aaaa">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**

Comment: that not work i give validation grop to all validation and aslo button

Comment: that i specify in my question

Comment: its backbone is html too, if you switch to source mode, which resides in the bottom of editor window, you have three option Design | Split | Source. Choose source and copy paste the code here.

Comment: ya that i do i also do code in source like:                             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/signin_button.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                    ValidationGroup="aaaa" CausesValidation="true" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                    Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="aaaa" Width="182px" />

Comment: also in text box like this:        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" CssClass="text_box_password" 
                    TextMode="Password" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="aaaa"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_password" ErrorMessage="*" 
                    ValidationGroup="aaaa">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: remove validation group from textbox. Use it only in validator.

Comment: i can't apply group to textbox. only apply to validator.... plz give me answer...........